# Authentication failed: ClientApplication.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'enable_pii_log' on Microsoft Graph Connection

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-sdks

I keep getting this error when I try to connect to Microsoft Graph using `msgraph-sdk`

`UsernamePasswordCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: ClientApplication.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'enable_pii_log`

I use this configuration

```
scopes = ['User.Read']

# Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
# single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
tenant_id = ''

# Values from app registration
client_id = ''

# User name and password
username = ''
password = ''

# azure.identity
credential = UsernamePasswordCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    username=username,
    password=password)

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes)
```

I really don't know how to fix the problem. Could you please help?

Thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Created an Azure AD application and enabled public client flows:

[image]

I used the below packages/modules and able to authenticate successfully:

```py
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from azure.identity import UsernamePasswordCredential
import asyncio
 
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
tenant_id = 'TenantID'
client_id = 'ClientID'
username = 'user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
password = '***'
 
async def main():
    credential = UsernamePasswordCredential(
        tenant_id=tenant_id,
        client_id=client_id,
        username=username,
        password=password)
 
    graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes)
 
    users = await graph_client.users.get()
    print(users.value)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Fetched users successfully:

[image]

The error usually occurs due the version mismatch of the packages.

- Try upgrading the make use of `pip install --upgrade msal azure-identity`
- And upgrade `pip install msal msgraph-sdk`
- If still the issue persists reinstall the packages and install `msgraph-core` version 1.0.0a4 and
  `msgraph-sdk` version 1.0.0a13 (*this version is working in my environment*).